# Linux Mint panel management

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Is there a primer on Linux Mint panel management? Problems: The panel does not resize dynamically (like in Windows) - If I add too many apps the panel just overflows off the end and some apps are not visible. Is there a way to expand the panel to 2 rows? I have 2 panels - how do I choose the panel I want to add the app to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual on the administration of the linux mint panel I have not found.

In case of having many applications in the panel it is recommended to have more than one panel. You can create a second panel, `right click`, `properties`, and set orientation to `bottom`, the new panel will be placed below the main panel, and you will have much more space to organize your applications. To place an application in the new panel, simply `left click` on the application you want to add, `add to panel`, the application will be added to the main panel, then `left click` on the application icon in the panel, `move`, and move it with the mouse to the bottom panel, then you can drop it where you want on the panel.

I also recommend that in case of opening many applications, use the work areas so as not to overcrowd the panel.